# Paypal Payout always return UNCLAIMED

Tags: paypal

I've been working with the payouts API, and I am having some troubles, this is the scenario:

When I pay to any user in the sandbox environment "mail-facilitator@gmail.com" everything works fine, the problem is when I go live or using any real paypal accounts in sandbox for some reason I always get "UNCLAIMED" "RECEIVER_UNREGISTERED" even though I'm very sure that the user have confirmed the email.

Any ideas of what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use live PayPal accounts to pay if your checkout is in Sandbox mode. Live and Sandbox cannot be mixed. If in Sandbox mode, you use Sandbox buyer accounts and if in live mode, you use live PayPal buyer accounts. An unclaimed payment means the seller email address being used is unconfirmed in the PayPal system and you would need to log in to your PayPal profile to confirm the email address.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem.